# Monorepo with Many npm-scripts

Tags: reactjs, lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

in your Monorepos is it normal for the root package.json to get many npm scripts as you get more and more packages? I am mapping all the scripts of the packages in root to make it easier, is it a good approach?
And it is normal when I need to develop dependent packages, like i18n lib which is installed in components lib which is installed in CRM. It’s normal for me to need to run all 3 on dev, right?

Answer (score 0):

First question to ask yourself is - do you need all those scripts to be defined?

Often just the most common scripts can be defined in `package.json`, and the rest mentioned in documentation.

---

If you want to have many scripts, and find yourself needing to run multiple ones, then [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) is a very useful package to run multiple scripts in serial or parallel, and can group/search by wildcard.

For example:

```
"scripts": {
   "test:frontend": "jest",
   "test:e2e": "cypress run",
   "test:scripts": "bash ./script.sh",
   "test": "npm-run-all --parallel test:**",
   "clean": "rimraf ./dist",
   "lint ": "prettier",
   "build:fe": "vue-cli-service build",
   "build:be": "node build.js",
   "prePublish": "npm-run-all --serial clean lint build:**"
}
```

Comment: Hi, Luke. Thanks for your response!
As I mentioned, I need to run many packages simultaneously and to avoid it, I heard recommendations to create a webpack configuration for the monorepo which points to all packages. Have you ever needed to do this?